# Handle many continuous request simulateously with Nginx

Tags: http, nginx

How should I configure nginx on my server (that has Core i7, one hard drive 1T, 16GB RAM) to handle 40 continuous request simulateously with Nginx? 
Any request take from 15 to 60 sec.

Thanks

Comment: If my answer is good for you could you accept it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard nginx conf file has this which enable much more than 40 simultaneous requests.

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
```

If your requests take a long time to process by your upstream server (I assume you're using Nginx as a reverse proxy), then you need to add this to your `server` or `location` block (wherever you `proxy_pass` the request), this will ensure that connections taking 3 minutes (180 seconds, to be safe) or less will not be met with a time out.

```
  proxy_read_timeout 180;
  proxy_connect_timeout 180;
```